# How to upload the Airflow dags(workflows) without going through kubectl?

Tags: python, kubernetes, workflow, airflow, kubectl

I've been using the kubectl to upload Airflow workflows to the kubernetes (/usr/local/airflow/dags) manually. It is possible to do this without using the kubectl? by using a python script? or something else? If it's possible would you be able to share your source? or your python script? Thanks, Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on your setup. E.G. We use AWS and so we have the DAGs syncing from an S3 bucket path every 5 minutes. We just put dags into S3. I see that some Kubernetes setups use a kind of shared volume defined by a git repository, that might also work. Airflow itself (the webserver(s), worker(s), nor scheduler) does not offer any hook to upload into the DAG directory.